# JavaScript/jQuery: How do you pass an element to a function as its 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you pass something to a function, as if it calls the function?

Say I have this function

```
function ShowId() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

and this HTML

```
<div id='div1'>
  <a class='link'>Some link</a>
</div>
```

I want to do this

```
$('div .link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').call(ShowId); // What is the right syntax?
});
```

and it should alert: `div1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a method of `function`s, so the order is the other way around:

```
ShowId.call($(this).parent('div'));
```

Though, passing as an argument is also usually viable:

```
function ShowId(elem) {
    alert($(elem).attr('id'));
}
```

```
ShowId($(this).parent('div'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost, try this:

```
ShowId.call($(this).parent('div'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the jQuery element:

```
function ShowId($this) {
  alert($this.attr('id'));
}

$('div .link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('div').call(ShowId($(this)));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$('div .link').click(function() {
  var parentObj = $(this).parent('div');
  ShowId(parentObj); // call the function with arguments simply
});
```

And your function will be:

```
function ShowId(that) {
  alert($(that).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your element as a object in your function-

```
$('div .link').click(function() {
  ShowId($(this).parent('div'));
});

function ShowId(Obj) {
  alert(Obj.attr('id'));
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/LhSz3/)